# (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json') in VS Code, but no error in Pycharm, why?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, pycharm, interpreter

i just shifted to VS Code from Pycharm. Now i am doing a very simple json.load action in my script, and a weird thing happens. I keep getting the error  `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'"`. However, when i open the same exact py file in Pycharm, it runs perfectly without any error.

Both of them are running on python 3.7 interpreter.
The VS Code one is from `opt/local/bin/python3.7`, while
the Pycharm one is from `usr/local/bin/python3.7`.

is this the reason for the error?

Answer (score 3):

The file or directory you are looking for in the python script depends on the path you run the python script. This is the key of this kind problem.

When you open the cmd and enter into the python script path to run the python script, you can easily understand how to set the file or directory path in your python script which you are running.

But when you running the same python script in IDEA, you will be confused with the path you should take to search the file or directory. At this time, you just need to find out which path you will be taken to run the commands. And some times it's different from the python script directory.

In VSCode, the default path of the terminal was the root directory of the project. And when you choose 'Run python file in terminal', the command of this action take, does not change the path of the terminal. So the file or directory path in python script should depends on the project directory(terminal path). And you can change this default directory in debug mode through "cwd" configuration, then when you debug the python script, you will find the terminal path had been changed to the path of 'cwd' set.

Just need to remeber, the path in the python script depends on the path which you are running the python script, and it's different from different IDEA.